What are the differences in interpolating values in go templating for Hugo - Scratch vs variables
I know very little golang and even less go templating.
However, I have programmed in several languages over my career. But I didn't take a structured approach to learning Golang. So this might be an obvious thing for seasoned golang developers.
I use hugo for my blog and love extending the theme and creating UI components that I didn't get straight out of the box.
I was recently working with a carousel shortcode for Hugo.
The shortcode at the moment assumes that all the data that is necessary for populating the slider-carousel is written in one yaml configuration. This is impractical if you have more than one carousel on your website and each need to display a different set of images.
I wanted to make this such that the shortcode took a parameter - name of the data-configuration file, so that each carousel on any page could show different sets of images.
The design meant that the Hugo's data directory would have the following structure:
data/
├── carousels/
│   ├── one.yaml
│   └── two.yaml

Where one.yaml and two.yaml contains the configuration for the respective carousel instances. The contents of the files would look something of the following format.
images: 
  - image: /images/carousel-test/1.jpg
    content_html: "1"
  - image: /images/carousel-test/2.png
    content_html: "2"

I created a test.md with the following code for rendering the carousel.
{{< carousel items="2" height="500" unit="px" duration="7000" dataSource1="one" dataSource2="two">}}

Now in order to create a carousel for the purpose of demonstrating the differences between Scratch.Get dataSource2 and using a variable - $dataSource1
I decided to modify the shortcode definition by first reading the argument for the data source - which would a configuration file for each carousel.
{{ .Scratch.Set "height" (.Get "height") }}
{{ .Scratch.Set "unit" (.Get "unit") }}
{{ .Scratch.Set "ordinal" .Ordinal }}
{{ .Scratch.Set "items" (.Get "items") }}
{{ $dataSource1 := ((.Get "dataSource1") | default "one") }}
{{ .Scratch.Set "dataSource2" ((.Get "dataSource2") | default "two") }}
<div id="carousel{{ .Ordinal }}" class="carousel" duration="{{ .Get `duration` }}">
  <p>Site.Data.carousels is {{ .Site.Data.carousels }}</p>
  <p>dataSource1 is set to {{ $dataSource1 }}</p>
  <p>dataSource2 is set to {{ .Scratch.Get "dataSource2"}}</p>
  {{ range $key, $value := .Site.Data.carousels }}
    <p> *** The <i>key</i> is <b>{{$key}}</b> while <i>value</i>: <b>{{$value}}</b>  </p>
    {{ if eq $key $dataSource1 }}
      <p>Key is indeed one!</p>
    {{end}}

    {{ if eq $key (.Scratch.Get "dataSource2") }}
      <p>Key is indeed two!</p>
    {{end}}
  {{end}}
    <div class="prev">&lsaquo;</div>
    <div class="next">&rsaquo;</div>
</div>

I would expect Key is indeed two! to be rendered on screen. However, it never happens. What is the correct way to read from Scratch in an if condition?
References:

Slider-Carousel
Data Templates in Hugo
Site Data in Hugo
Schortcode Scratch in Hugo
?


In your Go template, the issue might be with how you're comparing the keys in the range loop with the value of dataSource2. The comparison eq $key (.Scratch.Get "dataSource2") might not be working as expected due to the way you're accessing the value from .Scratch.


{{ .Scratch.Set "height" (.Get "height") }}
{{ .Scratch.Set "unit" (.Get "unit") }}
{{ .Scratch.Set "ordinal" .Ordinal }}
{{ .Scratch.Set "items" (.Get "items") }}
{{ $dataSource1 := (.Get "dataSource1") | default "one" }}
{{ .Scratch.Set "dataSource2" ((.Get "dataSource2") | default "two") }}

<div id="carousel{{ .Ordinal }}" class="carousel" duration="{{ .Get `duration` }}">
  <p>Site.Data.carousels is {{ .Site.Data.carousels }}</p>
  <p>dataSource1 is set to {{ $dataSource1 }}</p>
  <p>dataSource2 is set to {{ .Scratch.Get "dataSource2"}}</p>

  {{ range $key, $value := .Site.Data.carousels }}
    <p> *** The <i>key</i> is <b>{{$key}}</b> while <i>value</i>: <b>{{$value}}</b>  </p>
    
    {{ if eq $key $dataSource1 }}
      <p>Key is indeed one!</p>
    {{end}}
    
    {{ if eq $key ($.Scratch.Get "dataSource2") }}
      <p>Key is indeed two!</p>
    {{end}}
  {{ end }}
  
  <div class="prev">&lsaquo;</div>
  <div class="next">&rsaquo;</div>
</div>



Removed unnecessary parentheses around .Get "dataSource1".
Adjusted the comparison in the if condition for dataSource2 to use $.Scratch.Get instead of .Scratch.Get. This should ensure that the correct value is retrieved from the Scratch space.
With these changes, the comparison in the if condition for dataSource2 should work as expected, and "Key is indeed two!" should be rendered on screen if the key matches the value of dataSource2.

Thank you very much for answering and it seems to work just as you explained.
As a new golang programmer, I'd appreciate some detail on when should one use $.Scratch vs .Scratch? What is this notation called? What are the rules around this? Where can I read and learn more? If you could add that to the answer above I'll mark it as the accepted answer, as you have explained most of it already.
